# How to enable cookies for a pseudo-browser in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, cookies, indy

I was testing an app from Marco Cantu's Delphi 2009 Handbook. This app, called AnonAjax (page 200), has some interesting features to recognize certain elements from a Web page and list them. This app uses anonymous methods with an internal Indy HTTP client component used to access to a given URL. As part of this app's functionality, it loads the first image listed. That's great, but with a Web page using cookies it does not load the image properly. I've tried with **AllowCookies=true** but it does not work. How can I enable cookies for this app?

Answer (score 3):

you can attach a cookie manager (indy component) to the indy http client component.

Comment: I've attached TidCookieManager and same problem, I cannot view some pics.

Answer (score 1):

Indy 10's cookie management is currently undergoing a major rewrite to address many issues that it has.  It is likely that you are encountering a situation where the version of Indy you are using is either rejecting the server's cookies incorrectly, or is not sending them back to the server correctly.  Unfortunately, I do not have an exact ETA as to when the new cookie management code will be ready for public use, but it is very close, possibly by the end of this month if time permits.